# NewRelic java agent unable to identify .jks trust store

Tags: java, certificate, weblogic, newrelic, truststore

We are using a NewRelic java agent to monitor java application. The application uses a custom trust store with .jks extension. However the agent by default or by explicitly specifying the path to the trust store does not identify the trust store and throws an error.

How can we use this trust store without changing the extension as we need to use as it is.

> INFO: Using ca_bundle_path:
> D:\Java\jdk1.8.0_311\jre\lib\security\cacerts
> 2022-01-24T16:55:40,590+0530 [7048 1] com.newrelic ERROR: Unable to
> generate ca_bundle_path certificate. Verify the certificate format.
> Will not process further certs.
> java.security.cert.CertificateException: Could not parse certificate:
> java.io.IOException: Empty input

Answer (score 1):

The Java agent relies on the default X.509 CertificateFactory that only accepts `.pem` files.

Relevant lines:

```
try (InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(caBundlePath))) {
  CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
  // ...
  caCerts.add((X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(is));
  // ...
}
```

https://github.com/newrelic/newrelic-java-agent/blob/f18215d145bd6992c0fe74a8c503459799e108ca/newrelic-agent/src/main/java/com/newrelic/agent/transport/apache/ApacheSSLManager.java#L54-L58

If you can override the SPI for the X.509 CertificateFactory for one that accepts `.pks` files you might be able to use your file.